# How to use channel.overwritePermissions

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I am trying to set up a discord bot that each time I put in the command "!start" it will erase everything on a channel and start anew, opening permissions to write to everyone. (Assuming permissions were closed)

I've tried already with guild.member.roles, with channel.member.roles, I know this is probably so easy to solve and I am just stupid, but I am new to javascript and everything I saw on Google doesn't exactly work

```
    channel.overwritePermissions(
    guild.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Players"), { SEND_MESSAGES: true }
    );
```

Something like that, but it comes up with an error to identify roles

Comment: The Error would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change permissions for `@everyone`, you can use the following code:

```js
channel.overwritePermissions(message.guild.defaultRole, { SEND_MESSAGES: true });
```

Comment: Right, so I tried that and it worked, kind of. The error with roles was rectified with the message.guild.defaultRole method, but now it says channel is not defined, so I presume it doesn't know what channel id to work on, and I tried using the command 
channel = Client.get.channel("channel_id")[channel_id would be the id I would copy from Discord] but it says that Client is not defined, I don't really know what to do from there.

Comment: **A.** Use whatever variable your Discord client was created with. It might be `client`, `bot`, etc. (case sensitive). **B.** Use `message.guild.channels.get('idHere')` inside your message event.